# Devise, Action Mailer producing invalid reset password URL in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, actionmailer

so basically I'm struggling when actually trying to reset a user's password in production.  While the mail is actually sent, and it works on development, on production the link is generated like this:

```
http://myapp.com%20/users/password/edit?reset_password_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

The actual problem is the %20 that is being generated, since if I take it out, I'm redirected to the page I'm looking for. So how can I get rid of that %20?

Here's both my development and production rbs

development

```
config.cache_classes = false
  config.whiny_nils = true

  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :port =>           '587',
    :address =>        'smtp.mandrillapp.com',
    :user_name => ENV["SMTP_USER"],
    :password => ENV["SMTP_PWD"],
    :domain =>         'myapp.com',
    :authentication => :plain
  }

  config.active_support.deprecation = :log
  config.action_dispatch.best_standards_support = :builtin
  config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict
  config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5
  config.assets.compress = false
  config.assets.debug = true
```

production

```
  config.cache_classes = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  config.serve_static_assets = false

  config.assets.compress = true

  config.assets.compile = true

  config.assets.digest = true


  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'myapp.com'}

  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :port =>           '587',
    :address =>        'smtp.mandrillapp.com',
    :user_name => ENV["SMTP_USER"],
    :password => ENV["SMTP_PWD"],
    :domain =>         'myapp.com',
    :authentication => :plain
  }
```

Comment: The `%20` is URL encoding for the blank space. So, somewhere there is an extra space that's messing with your links. Did you generate your own devise views, or you're using the default ones?

Comment: I'm using the default ones, and I also thought it was for the blank space since config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'myapp.com'} was originally config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'myapp.com '} however now that you mention it, even after I made the change, it feels as if rails is not taking into account my production.rb file. I can say this because I also tested changing the smtp settings and it is still sending from the previous one...

Comment: Silly question maybe, but did you restart your rails app after changing those settings?

Comment: Yea,I did. Idk what may be casuing it no to load

Comment: What are you using for an app server? If it's Passenger, try restarting Apache or NGINX instead of using the 'touch to restart' trick (which has frequent reports of not actually working).

Comment: I'm actually using nginx, and I'm doing the restart via the sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart command, yet still ot getting it to restart :/

Comment: Did you wrote config.action_mailer.default_url_options in application.rb ?